# my html form tags are not redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, redirect

How can I let the button in my form tags redirect to another page when clicked?

I have searched lots of websites trying to find a solution to my problem but I still can't get it right, I made a form which I used java script to validate it, so when i click on the submit button it validates the inputs but it doesn't take me to another page so can someone plz look at my code and help me out.

I tried to remove the button outside of the form tags and it took me to another page but nothing gets validated as if I didn't add any java script to the form. I saw people using something called php but I didn't get what that was so can someone give me a way to make my form use the java script I added and then redirects me to another page

this is my code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carma Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./page2.css">
    <script defer src="./page2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
          <h1>carma</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" action="./page3.html" method="POST">
            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="firstname" class="heading">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text">
                <div class="error" id="er"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="lastname" class="heading">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text">
                <div class="error" id="er"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="email" class="heading">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
                <div class="error" id="er"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control">
                <label for="tely" class="heading">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="tely" name="tely" type="tel">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <button class="Start-btn" type="submit" value="submit">Next</button>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

------------------

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Rebrand-header;
    src: url(./fonts/Rebrand\ Light.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
    src: url(./fonts/Henderson\ Sans.otf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-bold;
    src: url(./fonts/HendersonSans\ Bold.otf);
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: 0;
    background-color: #f1eff4;
}

.header{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 41%;
}

.logo{
  background-image: url("./images/header\ 2.png");  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  
}

.header h1{
    font-family: Rebrand-header;
    color: #0c0c4c;
    font-size: 300%;
}

.heading{
    margin-left:10px;
    color: #0c0c4c;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
}

#all{
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#firstname{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#lastname{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#email{
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#tely{
    margin-top: 3px;
}



#form{
    width:300px;
    margin:5vh auto 0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
}

/*.btn{
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-size: 15px;
}*/

#form button{
    font-family: Henderson-Sana-basic;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:50%;
    color:white;
    background-color: #1c1ce5;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:80px ;
}

#form button:hover{
    color: #1c1ce5;
    background:white ;
}

.input-control{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.input-control input{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:9px;
    width:100%;
}

.input-control input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

.input-control.success input{
    border-color: #09c372;
}

.input-control.error input{
    border-color: #ff3860;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-control.error{
    color: #ff3860;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:9px;
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    .header{
        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-left: 19%;
        display: flex;
    }

    .logo{
        background-image: url("./images/header\ 2.png");  
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-top: 6%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        
      }

  }
```

-------------------

java script

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const tely = document.getElementById('tely');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    validateInputs();
});

const setError = (element, message) => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
    inputControl.classList.add('error');
    inputControl.classList.remove('success')
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';
    inputControl.classList.add('success');
    inputControl.classList.remove('error');
};

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

const isValidPhone = tely => {
    const phone = /^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/;
    return phone.test(tely);
}

const validateInputs = () => {
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const telyValue = tely.value.trim();

    if(firstnameValue === '') {
        setError(firstname, 'First Name is required');
    } else {
        setSuccess(firstname);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setError(email, 'Email is required');
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        setError(email, 'Provide a valid Email address');
    } else {
        setSuccess(email);
    }

    if(lastnameValue === '') {
        setError(lastname, 'Last Name is required');
    }else {
        setSuccess(lastname);
    }

    if(telyValue === '') {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number is required');
    } else if (!isValidPhone(telyValue)) {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number must be of 10 characters');
    } else {
        setSuccess(tely);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault() cancel the events which can be cancelable.
e.preventDefault() in your js file is preventing the submit action although the form is valid.
Get a boolean return from validateInputs() function and change your form.addEventListener like this.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
if(!validateInputs()){
    e.preventDefault();
}});
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work ,do u know any other way?

Comment: I searched more and what u said was right but I needed to add extra things

Comment: Thank you for ur help, it means a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

So if any one is struggling like I am just add this and it will work u just have to change .input-control with whatever class u called ur inputs by

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    
    validateInputs();
    
    console.log(isFormValid());
    if(isFormValid()==true){
        form.submit();
     }else {
         e.preventDefault();
     }

});

function isFormValid(){
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-control');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container)=>{
        if(container.classList.contains('error')){
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```